# Enabling keyboard backlight on Sony VAIO on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: keyboard, backlight, vaio, sony

After reading dozens of other posts and nothing seems to work, I've located "keyboard backlight" in the `/sys/module/sony_laptop/parameters/` module but don't know how to get it to switch on.

I've downloaded the Sony VAIO control center for Linux [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vaio-control-ce/) but don't know how to use it to enable the keyboard backlight. Can anyone help with that please?

I feel so close yet so far away. I've been trying to solve this problem for many days and hours so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Changing kbd_backlight file works but the problem remains after rebooting

Comment: Yes, my experience exactly.

Answer (score 2):

I found it.
Open nautilus first with

```
sudo nautilus
```

Navigate to

```
/sys/devices/platform/sony-laptop
```

There is a file called `kbd_backlight`

Open it, there should be a `0` or a `-1`. Edit it to just leave a `1`.
Done. I replace for a 0 and save, backlight instantly turns off, change again to 1 and instantly on. No reboot needed.
Hope it helps.

Comment: it's easier to use the terminal for that ;)

Comment: Ok. Go ahead and post the fix entirely for terminal. I proposed it this way, plain and simple

Comment: I tried that but when I changed the value, I got an error message that wouldn't let me save: Could not save the file “/sys/module/sony_laptop/parameters/kbd_backlight”. You do not have the permissions necessary to save the file. Please check that you typed the location correctly and try again.

Comment: I entered the correct password after entering sudo nautilus then got the above.

Comment: `sudo nano kdb_backlight` to quickly edit the file with super root permissions

Answer (score 0):

a simpler way to do NotNamed420's solution in a single line would be to run:

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/devices/platform/sony-laptop/kbd_backlight
```