# How to resume from suspend after open lid on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: suspend, laptop, 20.04, thinkpad, resume

I have just installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my new Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon Gen7. Most things work fine. However, closing the lid suspends the computer (as expected), but opening the lid does not resume. If I press the power button quickly, nothing happens. If I hold the power button for about one second, it resumes. I would like to make it resume just by opening the lid. How do I accomplish this?

```
cat /proc/acpi/wakeup
```

has the output

```
LID   S4    *enabled   platform:PNP0C0D:00
```

so [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/400955/how-can-i-enable-automatic-resume-on-lid-open) didn't help me.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1275078/ubuntu-20-04-wont-resume-after-suspend-lid-closed-and-then-opened

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but happened to find the solution inspired by this thread: [Enabling keyboard backlight on Sony VAIO on Ubuntu 19.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1191252/enabling-keyboard-backlight-on-sony-vaio-on-ubuntu-19-10)

Following the same procedure:

```
sudo nautilus
```

Then navigate to "/sys/devices/platform/(*your laptop OEM, in my case, sony-laptop)"

You'll find the file named "lid_resume_S3" "lid_resume_S4" and "lid_resume_S5": S3 is suspend, S4 is hibernate, S5 is power-off. Check the value, if it's -1 or 0, it means the function is disabled. You can change the value to 1 accordingly. My laptop resumed from suspend when the lid is opened after I made changed on files for S3 and S4.

Meanwhile, directly from Terminal:

```
sudo nano lid_resume_S3
```

should also work, but I didn't try.

Good luck.