# Ubuntu 20.04 won't resume after suspend (lid closed and then opened)

Tags: 20.04, suspend

I just did a clean install of Ubuntu 20.04 on a Lenovo X1 Carbon (2nd Gen).

After closing the lid to suspend when reopened it is impossible to resume from suspend. I have to turn the laptop off and then back on again.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Wake is always difficult in linux... You should seach in Google if something wrote some about your computer with some suspend, wake,... and your comuter name keywords.

Comment: I did that extensively before posting here. Telling me to google a solution is not helpful.

Comment: Most likely, resume worked except for the display (royal pain) - my situation too with an Acer Aspire 5 using the amdgpu driver.  Flying blind, I can still Ctrl-Alt-F1, login as root, and then reboot. This works as a recovery method but it is very user-unfriendly.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239125/how-to-resume-from-suspend-after-open-lid-on-ubuntu-20-04

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, the BIOS has options for how to handle power buttons, lid open/close, etc.  If it's never booted Ubuntu before, it would be useful to look over the BIOS settings.

Does the power LED indicator show it went into suspend?  If not, then the suspend process never completed.  This is likely to be a peripheral without suspend support.

When the lid is opened, does the power led still indicate suspend or does it indicate that it's running and trying to resume?  If the former, then the lid open signal was never received and this could be a BIOS or hardware issue.  If the later, try to ssh into the machine from another to see if you can tell what's going on.  Thia may not work of resume didn't get far enough.  Killing the X server will start a new login session and do a full reset of the graphics if it's the graphics that's hung up.  You can also try to pull up a terminal with ctrl-alt-fN and then return to the GUI which might bring it back.

If it looks like it started to resume and you close the lid again, does the LED go back into suspend?  If this is the case, ssh should work when the lid is up and that would be the best way to see what's happening.

You should also look at /var/log/kern.log to see how far it got if it started to resume, but couldn't finish or if it failed to completely suspend.  This could help narrow down the problem.  It generates quite a bit of noise when suspending and resuming.

If it fails to boot, wait a few minutes before power cycling so that anything waiting on timeouts might leave a log trace.  There could also be something slowing down the resume by waiting on a timeout, so try waiting 10 minutes or so before giving up on the resume and if it does resume, the logs should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

One of the typical problems is that instead of suspend it attempts to hibernate.
In order to hibernate it requires that at least you have as much swap memory available as RAM you have.
Can you check what's your configuration with:

```
free -h
```

After one of those incident you can also check logs for errors, for example:

```
cat /var/log/messages | grep -i "error"
cat /var/log/messages | grep -i "mem"
```

When that happens, can you still ping the laptop, or SSH into it from another computer in the same network?.
What is your video card, and have you installed special video drivers?.
Did you try what Richard Elkins suggested Ctrl + Alt + F1?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem after I updated my Nvidia drivers to 460. I went back to 450 and everything is fine for now.
[Driver I am using right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qARsp.png)

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue on Ubuntu 20.04 and I have been able to fix it simply by changing the nvidia drivers from 460 to 470.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with a fresh install on an older Dell laptop (D830/M4300). Technically, the laptop wouldn't even make it into suspend when I closed the lid and would require a hard reboot once the lid was re-opened.

My solution was actually very simple - I was still using the default x-org display driver.  My old Dell uses an Nvidia video chip - switching to the nVidia video driver and a reboot completely resolved my suspend issue.

Answer (score 0):

For laptops, it won't be a hardware issue if the function (lid open and close to resume or suspend) works in Windows OS. However, I find the settings in Ubuntu 20.04 are somehow disabled by default.

Here is the solution: https://askubuntu.com/a/1325773/1192664

I copy-paste here as well:

> ```
> sudo nautilus
> ```
>
> Then navigate to "/sys/devices/platform/(*your laptop OEM, in my case,
> sony-laptop)"
>
> You'll find the file named "lid_resume_S3" "lid_resume_S4" and
> "lid_resume_S5": S3 is suspend, S4 is hibernate, S5 is power-off.
> Check the value, if it's -1 or 0, it means the function is disabled.
> You can change the value to 1 accordingly. My laptop resumed from
> suspend when the lid is opened after I made changed on files for S3
> and S4.

Answer (score 0):

Mine does the same thing, except that it **does** wake up when I press the `PrtSc` button. I learned this by mashing the keyboard before rebooting.